# PHP , PDO , Foreign Key

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to php and currently doing my project. So this is the question that I have:

> [image]

In above interface, I have extracted Category Name and ID to the 'category name' combo box from category table. And after will this form, I should enter 'category ID' to the 'Item table', because category ID is foreign key of Item table

This is the code i have add

```
require_once '../../config/config.php';

$query = 'SELECT `category_id`, `category_Name` FROM `tbl_category`';

$tbl_category_category_ID = $query;
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$tbl_distributor_distributor_ID= $_POST['tbl_distributor_distributor_ID'];
$item_lowlevel = $_POST['item_lowlevel'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

    try {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_item`(`tbl_category_category_ID`, `item_name`, `price`, `tbl_distributor_distributor_ID`, `item_lowlevel`,`status`)
               VALUES (:tbl_category_category_ID, :item_name, :price, :tbl_distributor_distributor_ID, :item_lowlevel ,:status)";
        $qry = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $qry->execute(array(':tbl_category_category_ID' => $tbl_category_category_ID,
                            ':item_name' => $item_name,
                            ':price' => $price,
                            ':tbl_distributor_distributor_ID' => $tbl_distributor_distributor_ID,
                            ':item_lowlevel' => $item_lowlevel,
                            ':status' => $status));

        $conn = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

But this is the master table of 'item table'. It has just added the query. how do I correct this. How should I take category ID from combo box and enter it to the item table.

> [image]

Comment: i saw that you didn't execute your first query once you will execute your query then you will get the category id and store it in variable $tbl_category_category_ID instead of storing query

Comment: Are you not getting category ID from combo box  in POST variable? If not then the make sure that you sent category ID in POST . And also when you category details in combo box (that means you have already executed query on ``tbl_category``) so need to run that query again while trying to save data to ``item`` table.

Comment: Did you mean like this ?

then it become error like this


<?php

require_once '../../config/config.php';

$query = 'SELECT `category_id`, `category_Name` FROM `tbl_category`';

$tbl_category_category_ID = $_POST['$query'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$tbl_distributor_distributor_ID= $_POST['tbl_distributor_distributor_ID'];
$item_lowlevel = $_POST['item_lowlevel'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

Answer (score 0):

First you need to execute your select statement

Change this...

```
$query = 'SELECT `category_id`, `category_Name` FROM `tbl_category`';
```

To this...

```
$sql = "SELECT category_id, category_Name FROM tbl_category ORDER BY category_Name ASC";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Next create your select box using data from your select statement...

```
<select name="category_id" id="category_id">
<option value="">Select A Category</option>
<?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['category_Name'] ?></option>
<?php } while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
</select>
```

Finally get your category id
Change this...

```
$tbl_category_category_ID = $query;
```

To this...

```
$tbl_category_category_ID = $_POST['category_id'];
```

Comment: Thank your for the co operation , but the thing is I can successfully added data to the data base, retrieving gives the error. And again again thank you for your effort

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with adding anything to the database. It is for retrieving the data and using it in the select box.

Comment: Thanks very one ... !